# What is the value of $\tan (\theta) = 1/-1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, complex-numbers, angle

I am stuck in this complex number problem.

Let $z = -1 + 1i$. The polar form is $r = \sqrt 2$,  $\tan (\theta) = 1/-1$.

My question is that i cannot determine which quadrant this lies.

I saw an answer that $\theta = \tan^{-1}(1/(-1))$, which lies in 4th quadrant.

But the answer to this is $(3\pi)/4$.

My question is how can I get that this value lies in $Q2$.

What I understand is that since $\tan \alpha =\sin\alpha /\cos\alpha$.

Here sine is positive and cosine is negative so this should be $Q2$ and the angle from triangle is $\pi/4$ which is rhe reflection of $3\pi/4$.

Many thanks. Still confuse at this.

Comment: $\tan\theta=-1$ for $\theta=\dfrac34\pi+n\pi$

Comment: Well how you got 3*pi/4... can you explain the approach.

Comment: add $\pi$ to $-\dfrac\pi4$ because the real part of $z$ is negative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $z=-1+i=x+yi,$ with $x=-1$ and $y=1$.

Clearly $z$ is in the second quadrant, since $x<0$ and $y>0$.

The polar form is $z=r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$.

As you noted, $r=\sqrt2$.

Therefore, $\cos\theta=-\dfrac1{\sqrt2}$ and $\sin\theta=\dfrac1{\sqrt2}$,

so we can take $\theta=\dfrac{3\pi}4$.

Note that $\dfrac{\pi}2<\theta<\pi$, so $\theta$ is indeed in the second quadrant.

Comment: Thank you so much. Now its much clear.